# Rails4.1 validateで弾かれるとセレクトボックスの値が未選択状態に戻る

Tags: ruby-on-rails

親カテゴリと子カテゴリがあり、子カテゴリはAjax通信で動的に変わります。
validateエラーで差し戻された場合に、選択したカテゴリが未選択状態に戻ってしまうのですが
なぜでしょうか

#### View

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(categories.collect { |category|
[category.name, category.id.to_s] }),  {:include_blank =>  'plz select' },
{ id: 'category_select', class: 'form-control select select-default' } %>

<%= f.select :sub_category_id, options_for_select(sub_categories.collect { |child|
[child.name, child.id] }), {:include_blank =>  'plz select' },
{ id: 'sub_category_select' , class: 'form-control select select-default '} %>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('change', '#category_select', function(evt) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/items/list',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            category_id: $("#category_select option:selected").val()
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#sub_category_select").empty();
            if (data.length == 0) {
                $("#sub_category_select").hide();
            } else {
                $("#sub_category_select").show();
            }
            $.each(data, function(idx, sub) {
                // console.log("" + item.code + ":" + item.name);
                $("#sub_category_select").append('<option value="' + sub.id + '">' + sub.name + '</option>');
            });
            console.log("Dynamic country select OK!");
        }
    });
});
```

#### Log

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-06 14:47:05 +0900
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xm/qEvY8bH8JkkqNnOZ5XZgAxVCZLezaNSgYT4tVGLU=", "item"=>{"category_id"=>"280649686", "sub_category_id"=>"122837488", "picture_1_cache"=>"", "picture_2_cache"=>"", "picture_3_cache"=>"", "picture_4_cache"=>"", "title"=>"", "content"=>"", "condition_id"=>"963362593", "delivery"=>"false", "area"=>"1", "limit_day"=>""}, "commit"=>"送信"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."parent_id" IN (8375840, 34598291, 239096215, 280649686, 607038821, 692953909, 738355766, 832268406, 917391766, 959348699)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Condition Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conditions".* FROM "conditions"
  Rendered items/_form.html.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered pages/_precautions.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered pages/_business_day.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered pages/_privacy_policy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered items/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
  Todo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos"  WHERE ((exhibitor_id = 1 AND status = 'f') OR (proprietor_id = 1 AND status = 'f'))
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "todos"  WHERE ((exhibitor_id = 1 AND status = 'f') OR (proprietor_id = 1 AND status = 'f'))
  Notification Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE "notifications"."recipient_id" = 1 AND "notifications"."status" = 'f'
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered ideas/_form.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 26.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

#### Controller

```
  def new
    @item = current_user.items.build
  end

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'アイテムを登録しました' }

        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else

        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def list
    selected_category = Category.where(parent_id: list_params)
    childs = selected_category.sort{|a, b| a.code <=> b.code}
    data = []
    childs.each do |child|
      data << {id: child.id, name: child.name}
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: data }
    end
  end

  def list_params
    params.require(:category_id)
  end






#カテゴリセット
  def category_select
root = Category.find(1)
@categories = root.sub_categories.includes(:sub_categories).sort{|a, b| a.code <=> b.code}
@sub_categories = @categories[0].sub_categories.sort{|a, b| a.code <=> b.code}
  end
```

#### Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many   :sub_categories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :categories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

.

```
#親カテゴリ
Category.create(:name => 'root', :code => 000000, :parent_id => 0)
Category.create(:name => 'メンズ', :code => 100000, :parent_id => 1)#2
Category.create(:name => 'レディース', :code => 200000, :parent_id => 1)#3
Category.create(:name => 'キッズ', :code => 300000, :parent_id => 1)#4
Category.create(:name => 'インテリア', :code => 400000, :parent_id => 1)#5
Category.create(:name => '家電製品', :code => 500000, :parent_id => 1)#6
Category.create(:name => '本', :code => 600000, :parent_id => 1)#7
Category.create(:name => 'チケット', :code => 700000, :parent_id => 1)#8
Category.create(:name => 'おもちゃ', :code => 800000, :parent_id => 1)#9
Category.create(:name => 'エンターテインメント', :code => 900000, :parent_id => 1)#10
Category.create(:name => 'スポーツ', :code => 1000000, :parent_id => 1)#11


#メンズ子カテゴリ
Category.create(:name => 'トップス', :code => 100100, :parent_id => 2)
Category.create(:name => 'アウター', :code => 100200, :parent_id => 2)
Category.create(:name => 'パンツ', :code => 100300, :parent_id => 2)
Category.create(:name => '靴', :code => 100400, :parent_id => 2)
Category.create(:name => '帽子', :code => 100500, :parent_id => 2)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 100600, :parent_id => 2)

#レディース子カテゴリ
Category.create(:name => 'トップス', :code => 200100, :parent_id => 3)
Category.create(:name => 'アウター', :code => 200200, :parent_id => 3)
Category.create(:name => 'パンツ', :code => 200300, :parent_id => 3)
Category.create(:name => '靴', :code => 200400, :parent_id => 3)
Category.create(:name => '帽子', :code => 200500, :parent_id => 3)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 200600, :parent_id => 3)



#キッズ子カテゴリ
Category.create(:name => 'トップス', :code => 300100, :parent_id => 4)
Category.create(:name => 'アウター', :code => 300200, :parent_id => 4)
Category.create(:name => 'パンツ', :code => 300300, :parent_id => 4)
Category.create(:name => '靴', :code => 300400, :parent_id => 4)
Category.create(:name => '帽子', :code => 300500, :parent_id => 4)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 300600, :parent_id => 4)


#インテリア/家具の子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => 'ソファ/椅子', :code => 400100, :parent_id => 5)
Category.create(:name => 'テーブル/机', :code => 400200, :parent_id => 5)
Category.create(:name => 'ベット/寝具', :code => 400300, :parent_id => 5)
Category.create(:name => '収納', :code => 400400, :parent_id => 5)
Category.create(:name => '照明', :code => 400500, :parent_id => 5)
Category.create(:name => 'キッチン', :code => 400600, :parent_id => 5)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 400700, :parent_id => 5)



#家電製品の子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => 'パソコン/タブレット', :code => 500100, :parent_id => 6)
Category.create(:name => 'スマートフォン/携帯', :code => 500200, :parent_id => 6)
Category.create(:name => '生活家電', :code => 500300, :parent_id => 6)
Category.create(:name => 'オーディオ機器', :code => 500400, :parent_id => 6)
Category.create(:name => 'テレビ/映像機器', :code => 500500, :parent_id => 6)
Category.create(:name => 'カメラ', :code => 500600, :parent_id => 6)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 500700, :parent_id => 6)


#本の子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => '漫画/コミック', :code => 600100, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '文学/小説', :code => 600200, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => 'アート/エンターテインメント', :code => 600300, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => 'ノンフィクション', :code => 600400, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '雑誌', :code => 600500, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '人文/社会', :code => 600600, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '趣味/スポーツ', :code => 600700, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '住まい/暮らし', :code => 600800, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => 'ビジネス/経済', :code => 600900, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => 'コンピュータ/インターネット', :code => 401000, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '教育', :code => 601100, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => '医学', :code => 601200, :parent_id => 7)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 601300, :parent_id => 7)



#チケットの子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => '国内アーティスト', :code => 700100, :parent_id => 8)
Category.create(:name => '海外アーティスト', :code => 700200, :parent_id => 8)
Category.create(:name => 'イベント系', :code => 700300, :parent_id => 8)
Category.create(:name => 'スポーツ', :code => 700400, :parent_id => 8)
Category.create(:name => '演劇/舞台', :code => 700500, :parent_id => 8)
Category.create(:name => 'ミュージカル/お笑い', :code => 700600, :parent_id => 8)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 700700, :parent_id => 8)


#おもちゃの子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => 'テレビゲーム', :code => 800100, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'トレーディングカード', :code => 800200, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'フィギア', :code => 800300, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'プラモデル', :code => 800400, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'ラジコン', :code => 800500, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'ぬいぐるみ', :code => 800600, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'LEGO', :code => 800700, :parent_id => 9)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 800800, :parent_id => 9)




#エンターテインメントの子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => 'DVD/Blu-ray', :code => 900100, :parent_id => 10)
Category.create(:name => '楽器', :code => 900200, :parent_id => 10)
Category.create(:name => '美術品', :code => 900300, :parent_id => 10)
Category.create(:name => 'コレクション', :code => 900400, :parent_id => 10)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 900500, :parent_id => 10)


#スポーツの子カテゴリー
Category.create(:name => 'スポーツ用品', :code => 1000100, :parent_id => 11)
Category.create(:name => 'アウトドア用品', :code => 1000200, :parent_id => 11)
Category.create(:name => '自電車', :code => 1000300, :parent_id => 11)
Category.create(:name => 'フィッシング', :code => 1000400, :parent_id => 11)
Category.create(:name => 'その他', :code => 1000500, :parent_id => 11)
```

#### 2015.04.10 追記

1日かけてもまだ解決していません。
画面の状態は以下のようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> 画面表示直後のカテゴリ、サブカテゴリ周りのHTML

[image: 画面表示直後]

> カテゴリを変更し、選択できないテキストが表示されている状態のHTML

[image: カテゴリを変更し、選択できないテキストが表示されている状態のHTML]

> javascript

```js
0: option
1: option
2: option
3: option
4: option
5: option
6: option
7: option
accessKey: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
autofocus: false
baseURI: "http://0.0.0.0:3000/items/new/"
childElementCount: 8
childNodes: NodeList[8]
children: HTMLCollection[8]
classList: DOMTokenList[5]
className: "form-control select select-default sub-category-select select2-offscreen"
clientHeight: 15
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 220
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dir: ""
disabled: false
draggable: false
firstChild: option
firstElementChild: option
form: form#new_item.new_item
hidden: false
id: "item_sub_category_id"
innerHTML: "<option></option><option value="30">ソファ/椅子</option><option value="31">テーブル/机</option><option value="32">ベット/寝具</option><option value="33">収納</option><option value="34">照明</option><option value="35">キッチン</option><option value="36">その他</option>"
innerText: ""
isContentEditable: false
jQuery11020925654900027439: 2725
labels: NodeList[0]
lang: ""
lastChild: option
lastElementChild: option
length: 8
localName: "select"
multiple: false
name: "item[sub_category_id]"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "SELECT"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
offsetHeight: 15
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: div.col-sm-9.col-md-3.col-lg-3
offsetTop: 0
offsetWidth: 220
onabort: null
onautocomplete: null
onautocompleteerror: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectstart: null
onshow: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwheel: null
options: HTMLOptionsCollection[8]
outerHTML: "<select class="form-control select select-default sub-category-select select2-offscreen" id="item_sub_category_id" name="item[sub_category_id]" tabindex="-1" title=""><option></option><option value="30">ソファ/椅子</option><option value="31">テーブル/机</option><option value="32">ベット/寝具</option><option value="33">収納</option><option value="34">照明</option><option value="35">キッチン</option><option value="36">その他</option></select>"
outerText: ""
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div.col-sm-9.col-md-3.col-lg-3
parentNode: div.col-sm-9.col-md-3.col-lg-3
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: div#s2id_item_sub_category_id.select2-container.form-control.select.select-default.sub-category-select
previousSibling: div#s2id_item_sub_category_id.select2-container.form-control.select.select-default.sub-category-select
readOnly: false
required: false
scrollHeight: 15
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 220
selectedIndex: 0
selectedOptions: HTMLCollection[1]
shadowRoot: null
size: 0
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration
tabIndex: -1
tagName: "SELECT"
textContent: "ソファ/椅子テーブル/机ベット/寝具収納照明キッチンその他"
title: ""
translate: true
type: "select-one"
validationMessage: ""
validity: ValidityState
value: ""
webkitdropzone: ""
willValidate: true
```

> 画面表示直後のカテゴリ、サブカテゴリ周りのHTML子カテゴリ

[image: 子カテゴリ]

> javascript

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: このコードだけ見せられても何をどう困っているのかわからないので、説明を追記してください。

Comment: すいません、追加しました。どうでしょうか

Comment: コードブロックの作成は「半角スペース4つでインデント」です。テキストを範囲選択してから編集メニューにある「{ } 」ボタンをクリックしてもOKです。">"を使うと引用になるのでコードブロックには使わないで下さい。

Comment: { } 」ボタンをクリックしてもOKです。うまくいかないんですよね。。

Comment: 地元のRuby勉強会は参加者を写真を撮って毎回ネットにアップするのが
習慣となっているので、参加したくないんです。
写真撮らないでください、デバック一緒に手伝ってくださいというのも
あれですし、引き続き色々試してみます。

Comment: 情報を追記しました。 プロジェクト自体はgithubのプライベートに上げてあるのですが オープンネットワークラボに応募する予定なので関係者にしか開示できません 関係者になっていただければ良いのですが・・ とても素晴らしいプロジェクトで世界で初めてのサービスです。 ユーザに自由を提供し、強制的なトランザクションフィーから解放します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた点アップしました。
Select2を外すとはどういう意味でしょうか

Comment: 自身ではJavaScriptでselect2の記述はしていません
関係ないかもしれませんがhttp://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/というbootstrapフレームワークを使用しています。


現在はcategory-select-sandboxと同じ内容にしています。
（いろいろ触ってもダメだったので）

railsは独学で5ヶ月目です。
もともと営業しかしたことがないので、ひどいもんです。
あと少しでプロトタイプが完成するので、それから仲間を集めようと思います。
(知り合いはPHPしかできませんが・・)
DelayedJobで非同期処理実装して正しく動くかテストすれば完成です！

Comment: 失礼しました。flatuiのjavascriptコードですがapplication.rbに記述していたのを忘れていました。確かにselect2ですね。。$("select").select({dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse'});の2を消したら子カテゴリも表示されました。デザインは崩れますが

Comment: ありがとうございます！正しく動きました。
ご迷惑おかけしました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: おお、ようやく動いたんですね。良かったです！

Comment: お付き合い頂き、感謝しています！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「validateエラーで差し戻された場合」とあるので、おそらくフォームをサブミット（更新ボタン等をクリック）したときの話だと推測します。
なのでここではAjaxの話は直接関係しなさそうです。

「選択したカテゴリが未選択状態に戻ってしまう」のは親カテゴリ、子カテゴリ、どちらの話でしょうか？

とりあえず、`category.id.to_s`の`to_s`はいらない気がしますね。
最初はこれが原因かなと思いましたが、手持ちのRailsプロジェクトで試したところ特に変化はありませんでした。

あと、「子カテゴリが未選択になる」と仮定すると、`sub_categories`の中身が親カテゴリに関連するカテゴリになっていないから、という理由が推測されます。

いずれにせよ、正確な原因を推測するのにはまだ情報が不足しているので、下記のような情報を追記してください。

- Viewの全体像（最低限 `categories`や`sub_categories`を定義している部分）
- Controllerのコード
- 以下のようなSubmit時のログ

.

```
Started POST "/fruits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-06 04:07:13 +0900
Processing by FruitsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"igF7cN7KTp2JgokY1v1v6qGrb0mfC51hS1G9F4KxMtk=", "fruit"=>{"name"=>"Strawberry"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

### EDIT

> , :selected => f.object.category_id)を追加したところ親カテゴリはvalidate後も値を保持するようになりました。sub_categoryは, :selected => f.object.sub_category_id)を追加しても未選択状態に戻ってしまいます。 <%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(categories.collect { |category| [category.name, category.id.to_s] }, :selected => f.object.category_id), {:include_blank => '選択してください' }, { id: 'category_select', class: 'form-control select select-default' } %>

`selected`を追加すれば保持するようになった、っていうのがちょっと謎ですね・・・。
とはいえ、こちらではそれ以上追跡のしようがないのでとりあえず置いておきましょう。

一方、子カテゴリの方ですが、submit後、セレクトボックスを開いたときに選択されるべき項目は含まれていますか？
たとえば、submit前に「野菜 > にんじん」と選択したのであれば、submit後も子カテゴリのセレクトボックスに「にんじん」が入って必要があります。

もし入っていないのであれば、`options_for_select(sub_categories.collect ...`の`sub_categories`の中身が正しく設定されていないことになります。

一方、入っているのであれば`sub_categories`が持っている`id`と`f.object.sub_category_id`の中身が何らかの理由でマッチしていないんだと思います。

`<% Rails.logger.debug sub_categories.inspect %>`や`<% Rails.logger.debug f.object.sub_category_id %>`のようなデバッグコードを仕込んで、viewが受け取っているオブジェクトの中身を検証してみてください。

### EDIT 2

> sub_categoriesはnilでした。 .to_sがないと動かなくなったりするのもおかしいのですし もうバグだらけでhogehogeって感じです。

新しく情報を追加してもらいましたが、`category_select`がどこでどのように呼ばれているのか、といった情報もないと意図した通りのデータが得られない理由も推測しにくいです。

いずれにせよ、スタックオーバーフロー上で情報のキャッチボールをしていても原因と解決策が見つかるまでにはかなり時間がかかりそうです。
こういったデバッグは実際にコードの全体像やアプリの動きを見ながら進めるのが一番良いので、一緒にデバッグしてくれる友人や同僚に付き合ってもらうのが一番の近道かなと思います。

そういった技術者が見つからない場合はお近くのRuby勉強会に飛び込んで「教えてください！」と頼んでみるのはいかがでしょうか？

### EDIT 3

若干仕様は異なりますが、ほぼ同じ事が実現できるサンプルアプリを作ってみました。

[image]

ソースコードはこちらにあります。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/category-select-sandbox

まずこれをローカルで動かしてみて、自分のコードと比較してみるとデバッグも少し効率よく進むかもしれません。
参考にしてみてください。

### EDIT 4

> サブカテゴリは表示されるのですが selectできないテキストで表示されます

おそらくselect boxじゃないオブジェクトに対してoptionをappendしてしまってるんだと思います。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/category-select-sandbox/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/items.coffee#L14

↑このセレクタで正しくselect boxを選択できているか確認してください。

ちなみにクライアントサイド（ブラウザ側）のデバッグはChrome デベロッパーツールのようなツールを使いこなさないとかなり大変です。
逆に言うと、こうしたツールが使いこなせれば、なぜうまく動かないのか自分で解決できるようになります。
もしこういったツールをうまく使えていないのであれば、まずツールの使い方を学習するのが先決かもしれません。

### EDIT 5

質問で挙げられている設計とは若干異なりますが、こちらに解説記事を書きました。
良かったらこちらも参考にしてみてください。

[Ajaxでセレクトボックスの中身が動的に変わるRailsアプリの作り方](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/59a5f6bea3d7be84b839)

### EDIT 6

Chromeデベロッパーツールを使って以下の情報を追記してください。

1. 画面表示直後のカテゴリ、サブカテゴリ周りのHTML
2. カテゴリを変更し、選択できないテキストが表示されている状態のHTML
3. サブカテゴリを置き換えているJavaScript

HTMLは下図のようにセレクトボックスを右クリックして「要素の検証」を選ぶと表示されます。（「ソースの表示」ではありません）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もしくは可能であればプロジェクト全体のソースコードをGitHub等に公開してもらった方が解決が早いかもしれません。

### EDIT 7

追記ありがとうございます。
[Select2](https://select2.github.io/)を使ってるようですね。
おそらくSelect2が動的に要素を変更するので、EDIT 3で示したようなシンプルなサンプルアプリと状況が変わっているんだと思います。
一度Select2を外して素のHTMLで動作させてみてください。

それから追記してもらった「画面表示直後のカテゴリ、サブカテゴリ周りのHTML」ですが、親カテゴリのHTMLしか見えていません。
サブカテゴリのHTMLも表示してください。（たぶんセレクトボックスが見えていなくてもdivタグぐらいは出ているはず）

あとJavaScriptはapplication.jsのようなソースコード（changeイベントを処理している部分）を見せてください。

### EDIT 8

Select2を外す = Select2を使わない、という意味です。
おそらくどこかのJavaScriptで `$('select').select2();` みたいなコードを書いたんじゃないでしょうか？
そこをコメントアウトすればSelect2は動作しないはずです。

あと、追記してほしかったJavaScriptは一番最初に書いてあった `$(document).on('change', ...` みたいなコードです。
全く手を加えていないなら追記しなくても良いですが、試行錯誤の過程で手を加えてあるならもう一度JSのコード全体を見せてください。

P.S.
ちなみにkitaさんは独学でプログラミングをされているのでしょうか？（僕にはそのように見えます）
やはりオンラインのやりとりだけではなかなか先に進まないので、kitaさんには席を並べて一緒にプログラミングやデバッグをしてくれる仲間や師匠が必要な気がします。

### EDIT 9

Flat UIを組みこんで動かしてみました。
こんな感じでイメージは合っていますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ソースコードはこちらにあります。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/category-select-sandbox/tree/select-2

EDIT 3のコードとのdiffはこちらです。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/category-select-sandbox/pull/1/files

#### ポイント1：JSで操作するセレクトボックスはclassでなく、idで指定する

以下はViewのコード（diff）です。

```
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
-    <%= f.select :category_id, category_collection(Category.find_by_name('root')), {include_blank: true}, {class: 'category-select'} %>
+    <%= f.select :category_id, category_collection(Category.find_by_name('root')), {include_blank: true}, {id: 'category-select', class: 'form-control select select-primary select-block mbl'} %>
   </div>
   <% style = "display:none;" if @item.category.try(:sub_categories).blank? %>
   <div class="field field-sub-category" style="<%= style %>">
     <%= f.label :sub_category_id %><br>
-    <%= f.select :sub_category_id, category_collection(@item.category), {include_blank: true}, {class: 'sub-category-select'} %>
+    <%= f.select :sub_category_id, category_collection(@item.category), {include_blank: true}, {id: 'sub-category-select', class: 'form-control select select-primary select-block mbl'} %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
-    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
+    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-info' %>
   </div>
```

classにすると、Select2が同じクラス名をコピーしてしまい、JSの処理時にHTMLがおかしくなります。

#### ポイント2：オプションを入れ替えたら`select2`メソッドをもう一度呼び出す

以下は`items.coffee`のコードです。

```
         $.ajax
           url: url
           dataType: "json"
           success: (results) ->
             $('.field-sub-category').toggle(results.length > 0)
-            $select.empty()
+            resetSelect($select)
             appendOptions($select, results)
+            $select.select2
+              dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse'
```

`appendOptions`でオプションを入れ替えた後に、`$select.select2`をもう一回呼び出しています。

#### ポイント3：オプションを入れ替える前にSelect2の内容も一緒にクリアする

以下は`items.coffee`のコードです。

```
+    resetSelect = ($select) ->
+      $select.empty()
+      $select.select2('val', '')
```

`$select.select2('val', '')`でSelect2の中身をクリアしています。
オプションを入れ替える前にこれを呼び出さないと、オプションがどんどん追記されてしまいます。

参考までに、JavaScriptに変更した後のコードも載せておきます。

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("select").select2({
      dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse'
    });
    return (function() {
      var appendOptions, replaceSubCategoryOptions, resetSelect;
      appendOptions = function($select, results) {
        var option;
        option = $('<option>');
        $select.append(option);
        return $.each(results, function() {
          option = $('<option>');
          option.val(this.id);
          option.text(this.name);
          return $select.append(option);
        });
      };
      resetSelect = function($select) {
        $select.empty();
        return $select.select2('val', '');
      };
      replaceSubCategoryOptions = function() {
        var $select, url;
        url = $(this).find('option:selected').data().subCategoriesPath;
        $select = $(this).closest('form').find('#sub-category-select');
        if (url != null) {
          return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(results) {
              $('.field-sub-category').toggle(results.length > 0);
              resetSelect($select);
              appendOptions($select, results);
              return $select.select2({
                dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse'
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          $('.field-sub-category').hide();
          return resetSelect($select);
        }
      };
      return $('#category-select').change(replaceSubCategoryOptions);
    })();
  });

}).call(this);
```

以上のようなコードを参考にするとうまくいくのではないでしょうか？
試してみてください。

Comment: ちなみに `:selected` が指定されてないことはあまり関係ないのでしょうか？

Comment: `= f.select :category_id`のように書いてあるので、`form_for`で指定されているオブジェクトのcategory_idと同じ項目が自動的に選択状態になるはずです。参考 => http://railsdoc.com/references/select

Comment: 親カテゴリ、子カテゴリ両方が未選択状態になります。
category.id.to_sのto_sを取ると子カテゴリがnilになります。
（子カテゴリ候補が何も出てこない）

categoriesやsub_categoriesはツリー構造でcategory modelに親idと子idカラムがあって入れ子になってます。


:selectedについては調べてみます。

Comment: , :selected => f.object.category_id)を追加したところ親カテゴリはvalidate後も値を保持するようになりました。sub_categoryは, :selected => f.object.sub_category_id)を追加しても未選択状態に戻ってしまいます。


<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(categories.collect { |category|
                                                            [category.name, category.id.to_s] }, :selected => f.object.category_id),  {:include_blank =>  '選択してください' },
                         { id: 'category_select', class: 'form-control select select-default' } %>

Comment: 編集していただいてありがとう御座います。なぜかうまくコードが貼れません
サブカテゴリには別のサブカテゴリの値が入っていました。
(プライマリidで一番最初の親カテゴリのサブカテゴリが入っている状態)

デバックはこれからやります。

Comment: sub_categoriesはnilでした。
.to_sがないと動かなくなったりするのもおかしいのですし
もうバグだらけでhogehogeって感じです。

Comment: ソースコードありがとうございます。
自分の環境で当てはめてやってみました。
親カテゴリを選択すると、サブカテゴリは表示されるのですが
selectできないテキストで表示されます。
そのままsubmitを押してバリテーションから差し戻されると
ちゃんとsekect boxになっているのですが。。

Comment: コードは改変していないので動くと思ったのですが
select boxじゃないオブジェクトに対してoptionをappendの意味がわからないので調べてきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。EDIT 3のコードは自分のローカル環境ではただしく動きます。そこから自分の開発しているプロジェクトに当てはめるとselectできないテキストが表示されます。同じコードなのに挙動が異なるのは私のプロジェクト側に何か問題があるということでしょうか